# How to make menu and submenu dynamic Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to make menu and submenu dynamic .I made menu with their link but unable to make submenu,please help me my database structure

table name:`menu`

```
id              menu_name       url                timestamps
```

table:`sub_menu`

```
id      submenu_name       link      menu_id  timestamps
```

my query is like this

```
public function menu()
{   
   $sql=\DB::table('menu')->rightjoin('sub_menu','menu.id','=','sub_menu.menu_id')
   ->select('submenu_name','link','url','menu_id','menu_name','menu.id')->get();
    return view('products.show.menu',compact('sql'));
}
```

view

```
<ul>    
    @foreach($sql as $key => $nav)
      @if($key > 0)
        <li>
            <a href="#">{{$nav->menu_name}}</a>
             @if (count($nav->submenu_name) > 0 )
                <ul>        
                 @foreach($nav->submenu_name as $child)
                    <li><a href="#">{{$child->submenu_name}}</a></li>
                @endforeach
                @endif
                </ul>
        </li>
      @endif
    @endforeach
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you set up models for these tables? Your query will return multiple rows for each menu/submenu combination, meaning you can't just iterate over it as you are. There's no need to use the query builder here.

Assuming your models are set up as follows (you will need to check the namespace used in the relationships):

```
class Menu extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'menu';

    public function submenu()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\SubMenu');
    }
}

class SubMenu extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'sub_menu';

    public function menu()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Menu');
    }
}
```

In your controller, you can do:

```
public function menu()
{
    $menu = Menu::with('submenu')->get();

    return view('products.show.menu', compact('menu'));
}
```

Then in your view:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($menu as $menuItem)
        <li>
            {{ $menuItem->menu_name }}
            @if( ! $menuItem->submenu->isEmpty())
                <ul>
                    @foreach($menuItem->submenu as $subMenuItem)
                        <li>{{ $subMenuItem->submenu_name }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            @endif
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: many thnaks but $menu=Menu::all()->load('submenu') worked correctly than   $menu = Menu::with('submenu')->all();

Comment: Yeah, I may have been better using `->get()` - have amended :)

Comment: benJ how to do this with one menu table with parent_id column using one model?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it without controller

```
`@foreach(App\Menu::get() as $menuItem)
  @if( ! $menuItem->submenu->isEmpty() )
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
        {{ $menuItem->menu_name }}
    </a>
  @else
    <li>
    <a href="{{ $menuItem->url }}">{{ $menuItem->menu_name }}</a>
  @endif

  @if( ! $menuItem->submenu->isEmpty())
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          @foreach($menuItem->submenu as $subMenuItem)
              <li><a href="{{ $subMenuItem->link }}">{{ $subMenuItem->submenu_name }}</a></li>
          @endforeach
      </ul>
  @endif
  </li>
@endforeach`
```